# Create an Image ListView from a java array

Tags: android, android-listview

I know how to create a ListView for images that are in the drawable folder, by creating an array that contains items that each one are drawable resources. and then by using a list and image adapter we get a photo listview.

I have a regular java array, that contains strings that represent the picture i want to include in the listview, how to create form this string array an image ListView?

thank you

Comment: Are these `Strings` URL's? Can you post your code so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: Does this string array of yours contain URL's to the image or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html)
and then [setViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder%29). Before binding each element of the list you will get a callback on

```
setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation)
```

Depending on the textRepresentation you can setImage and then return true for only this case.